# Access variables from callback scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, security

I'm working on a web server development in node js where the request handler will be as follow;

```
function handler(request, response, give){
 var dbInstance = give("db instance");
 //..
}
```

This is how the handler will be called;

```
routesManager.prototype.register = function( httpMethod, url, handler ){

    this.router.on( httpMethod, url, async ( request, response, params ) => {
        var store  = this.store;            
        handler(request, response, function (str) {
            return store.get(str);
        });
    });
}
```

So the store is accessible from the callback. Can it be accessed from handler as well? I want to keep it protected from any direct use.

Comment: Where do you initialize the `store`? Can you provide wider code examples?

Comment: Tried to add more code. Hopefully it would be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Store** is accessible for **handler callback** via the closure. It's not accessible for **handler** itself as soon as handler hasn't been defined at the same scope as the store. So, relax :)

The only way to pass store to handler is to bind handler to **this** in that context where it is currently called in your code, and  then call handler.

Comment: grt thanks. As I read somewhere, in javascript you can access everything, I was wondering how to hide **store** from handler